# IIS - Mapping one extension to another

Tags: iis, webserver, mapping, mime-types, file-extension

I did a bit of search but can't find a complete answer to my question:
I wonder if it's possible to set my IIS 7.5 to map one "custom" extension to another "physical" extension.

Eg.
I have *Default.aspx*, I'd like my server to serve this file to a request of *Default.foo*.

The mapping questions/answers I found are all about having *Default.foo* files, and mapping them to the proper handler; that's not my case, I just like to have a sort of *masking* of the real physical file extension.

Is it possible?

TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping should be setup between default.foo and default.aspx, mapping extensions cannot achieve this goal. You may use [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module to [create a rule](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) to rewrite default.foo to default.aspx.

A simple example is as below,

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="foo" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)\.foo" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```